# Angular.js scope variable undefined, ng-repeat initial state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i've recently started playing with angular & node, and immediately i've ran into issues.

I have a simple Controller, which is used to fetch single object. All works fine, but i would like to be able to initialize scope variable within controller. I have no idea how to do this, i always end up with "variable undefined" or empty data provided by controller.

```
function FightCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {

var addNewCard = function(myDeck, data){
    if (myDeck === undefined){
        myDeck = []; //doing it this way, i no longer have exception with
                  //"undefined" myDeck variable, but no data is shown in webpage
    }
    myDeck.push({
        myCard: data.card
    });
    return myDeck;
};

$scope.generateMyCard = function() {
  $http.get('/api/fight/').
    success(function(data) {
        //simple, but works only for one fetched item (card)
        //namely: i cannot use ng-repeat here :(
        $scope.myDeck = {
            myCard: data.card //"data.card" fetched by node, works like a charm
        };

        // this one is not working, and i would like to use something like this
        //instead of solution presented 3 lines above
        //$scope.myDeck = addNewCard($scope.myDeck, data);
    });
};}
```

What could be wrong here? How could i fix it?

My guess is: $scope.myDeck is not initialized properly, but i have no idea how to fix it.

btw. from html point of view, all is ok, im just using ng-repeat='myCard in myDeck'. I can observe in gui consecutive elements when i add them but no data is present.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise myDeck in the body of the controller like so:

```
function FightCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {

   $scope.myDeck = [];

}
```

and you should be good to go.

You could also simplify the adding of card in the success handler to:

```
$scope.myDeck.push( { myCard : data.card });
```

Comment: Already tried that, and this actually prevents "undefined" variable, but still no data is present in there. Maybe i should initialize it in some specific way, as it is supposed to be an array?

Comment: The statement $scope.myDeck = []; is creating the array. You then need to push cards into this array as they arrive.

Comment: Although now im facing new problems with `$digest` i guess you deserve the "accepted answer" since you covered my question, and even gave me a hint how to improve my code. Thanks for the quick help ;)